# Representation of random variable as vectors

Tags: vectors, random-variables, independence, correlation

I came across this course the other day: `http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/lecture12.pdf`
in which I think the teacher is trying to explain correlation geometrically.

The thing is I don't really get the mapping between vectors in Rn and random variables, especially at this point:

[image: not so obvious relation]

What bother me is that this is presented as being a somehow incredible result but I don't get the idea. In particular what exactly is f()?

example [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4x1Z.png) is also all greek to me: 
[image]
[image]

what does "we can center them to get centered random variables which are independent" mean?

Thanks in advance for your help, please do tell me if you think I am not clear enough, I can't help thinking there is an important point that I am missing here and I would really like to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your first question:

If $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ is a probability space then a random variable on it is a function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ such that $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal A$ for every Borel set $B$.

Now realize that $\mathbb R^n$ can be looked at as the set of functions $\{1,\dots,n\}\to\mathbb R$.

E.g. vector $(4,7.3)^T$ corresponds with the function $\{1,2\}\to\mathbb R$ that sends $1$ to $4$ and sends $2$ to $7.3$.

So if we go for $\Omega=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and equip it with $\sigma$-algebra $\wp(\{1,\dots,n\})$ and some probability measure $P$ then elements of $\mathbb R^n$ (vectors) are exactly the corresponding random variables.

A good candidate for $P$ is of course the map $A\mapsto\frac1n|A|$.

Comment: Thanks @drhab for trying to help me! What I still don't understand is what the vectors' values represent. E.g. in your example, what does 4 and 7.3 represent? Or if n=5, what would be the difference between (0.1,0,0,0,0.1) and (1000,0,0,0,500) ? I don't see where the probabilities appear in this representation.

Comment: Probability comes in if you have defined a probability measure $P$ on the space. If for instance $n=2$ and you take the candidate mentioned in my answer then the random variable $X$ represented by vector $(4,7.3)$ has properties like $P(X\in (1,5))=P(\{1\})=\frac12$ and  $P(X>7)=P(\{2\})=\frac12$.